# set fetched data from database to a textview after calling intent

Tags: android, database, android-intent

I've created a `Textview`  with a `null` value and button in my my `Mainactivity` and fetched some data from `sql database server` using `AsyncTask` method on button click and stored in to my `textview`. 
Then I called an intent to another `activity` activity2 to show something and I returned to my `Mainactivity` using intent.But I can't view the previously set data in `textview`. It shows `null` value.I want to set it previously fetched data.how can I set that?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public ImageView prev, now, next;
    String depvisitid;
    public TextView display, bottom, ptname, docname;
    public String tokenh,tokenext,tokennow;
    public String pname,pnamenext,pnamenow;
    public boolean status;
    public String drname,current;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        prev = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.previmg);
        now = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.token);
        next = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nextimg);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        ptname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        bottom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tokennum);
        docname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

      //  Connect runner = new Connect();
      //  runner.execute();
```

The setOnClickListener method:

```
    prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            //  String sleepTime = time.getText().toString();

        }
    });
    now.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            display.setText(tokenh);
            ConnectNow nw = new ConnectNow();
            nw.execute();

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StatusUpdate.class);
            i.putExtra("patientname", pname);
            i.putExtra("tokenno", tokenh);
            i.putExtra("depvisitid", depvisitid);

            startActivity(i);




        }

    });

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Connect runner = new Connect();
            runner.execute();

        }
    });




}
```

The onBackPressed:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //  super.onBackPressed();
    // finish();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

class Connect extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        String username = "aaa";
        String password = "sssss";
        Connection DbConn = null;
        try {
            DbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.x.x:1433/DATABASENAME;user=" + username + ";password=" + password);
            Log.i("Connection", "openjjj");

        } catch (SQLException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.w("Connection", "open");
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            stmt = DbConn.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        ResultSet reset1 = null;


        try {
            reset1 = stmt.executeQuery(" select a.TOKENNO,b.FNAME,a.TOKENSTATUS,e.EMPFNAME,a.DEPVISITID from DEPTVISIT a,PATIENT_MASTER b,APP_EMPLOYEE e  where a.PID=b.PID and (a.TOKENSTATUS='O' or a.TOKENSTATUS='S' ) and e.EMPID=a.EMPID and a.EMPID=2 and CONVERT(date,a.OPDATE)='2016-05-09' order by TOKENNO desc;");
            while (reset1.next()) {

                tokenh = reset1.getString("TOKENNO");
                pname = reset1.getString("FNAME");
                drname = reset1.getString("EMPFNAME");
                depvisitid= reset1.getString("DEPVISITID");
            }


        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            DbConn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return tokenh;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


        bottom.setText(tokenh);
        ptname.setText(pname);
        docname.setText(drname);


    }




}
```

The connect now class:

```
class ConnectNow extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
       try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        String username = "aaaaa";
        String password = "ssssss";
        Connection DbConn = null;
        try {
            DbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.x.x:1433/DATABASENAME;user=" + username + ";password=" + password);
            Log.i("Connection", "openjjj****");

        } catch (SQLException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.w("Connection", "open****");
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            stmt = DbConn.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }



        try {
            int noOfRows = stmt.executeUpdate(" update DEPTVISIT set TOKENSTATUS='S' where DEPVISITID=" + depvisitid);
            if (noOfRows > 0) {
                status = true;
                System.out.println("status updated to S");
            }



        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            DbConn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return status;

  }
 protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {


        bottom.setText(tokenh);
        ptname.setText(pnamenext);
        docname.setText(drname);


    }


}
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

        Intent settings=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Settings.class);
        startActivity(settings);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

SECOND ACTIVITY   StatusUdate.java:

```
public class StatusUpdate extends Activity {
    public String tokenstatN, tokenstatY;


    Button visited, notvisited;
    String pname,tokennum,depvisitid;
    TextView patnam,tknum;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.statusupdate);
        visited = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        notvisited = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        patnam= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        tknum= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        pname = extras.getString("patientname");
        tokennum = extras.getString("tokenno");
        depvisitid = extras.getString("depvisitid");

        patnam.setText(pname);
        tknum.setText(tokennum);

        visited.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Visit vt= new Visit();
                vt.execute();

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        notvisited.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               NotVisit n = new NotVisit();
                n.execute();

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
```

The NotVisit class:

```
   class NotVisit extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {

        boolean status = false;

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

            } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            String username = "aaaaa";
            String password = "sssss";
            Connection DbConn = null;
            try {
                DbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.x.x:1433/DATABASENAME;user=" + username + ";password=" + password);
                Log.i("Connection", "openhhhh");

            } catch (SQLException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.w("Connection", "openlll");
            Statement stmt = null;
            try {
                stmt = DbConn.createStatement();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {

                int noOfRows = stmt.executeUpdate("  update DEPTVISIT set TOKENSTATUS='N' where DEPVISITID=" + depvisitid);
                if (noOfRows > 0) {
                    status = true;
                }


                try {
                    DbConn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }


            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("status", String.valueOf(status));
            return status;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you finishing the Activity? Please show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you wish to go to previous screen, Always finish the `Activity` that is on top. Here in your case, You are always creating new instance of `MainActivity` and this is the reason for getting null when you go back. Try using this in your `StatusUpdate.java`.

```
visited.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Visit vt= new Visit();
            vt.execute();

            StatusUpdate.this.finish();
        }
});

 notvisited.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           NotVisit n = new NotVisit();
           n.execute();

           StatusUpdate.this.finish();
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the retrieved text in a static field of your activity class, but it's better save and restore it on activity recreation.
So modify your activity like:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
  // activity initialization
  // textView = ... 
  if (b != null) {
    textView.setText(b.getString("dbtext"));
  }
}
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle b) {
   super.onSaveInstanceState(b);
   b.putString("dbtext", textView.getText());
}
```